# How to access the PHP file inside the WordPress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes

I have a folder structure like below

```
Project-1
 .header.php
 .footer.php
Project-2
Project-3
wp-admin
wp-content
wp-includes
.
.
.
all WordPress files
```

Now, I have `header.php` and `footer.php` files in my Project-1 folder. I am able to access both files in Project-2 and Project-3 using include('').

My issue is, I have to use the `header.php` and `footer.php` files in the WordPress root folder. I added below code `/wp-content/theme/themename/header.php`

```
<?php include('https://test.com/Project-1/header.php');?>
<?php include('https://test.com/Project-1/footer.php');?>
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace url with local path

```php
# use ABSPATH defined by wordpress
<?php include(ABSPATH . '/Project-1/header.php');?>
# or hardcode the path 
<?php include('/localpath/Project-1/header.php');?>
```

Comment: but i don't have my files inside ABSPATH

Comment: ABSPATH is the root path of wordpress, your projects and wordpress are all in the same directory, so it should work